# How to solve race condition for refresh api token during multiple async requests?

Tags: javascript, rest, oauth, oauth-2.0

There are like 5 async requests running at the same time that hit 401 response, and the default compensation function for it is to attempt to refresh the token to see if we can get granted access.

The problem is that if there are 5 async calls to refresh token endpoint, then we end with desynced, invalid token in our session.

This is Redux-Saga app with ReactJS on top of it.

Comment: Create a proxy object to coordinate refreshing the token. If there is a request already in flight, wait for that. Or if you don't want to wait, have the proxy send off another request and then have the proxy decide which response to use (presumably the first success), and use this response to notify all the callers of the proxy.

Answer (score 2):

You need to receive some kind of signal when those five requests are done. You can do it using `Promise.all` which takes an array of promises and fulfill when all promises are fulfilled and rejects when at least one does.

```
const asyncRequest1 = makeAsyncRequestPromise();
const asyncRequest2 = makeAsyncRequestPromise();
const asyncRequest3 = makeAsyncRequestPromise();
const asyncRequest4 = makeAsyncRequestPromise();
const asyncRequest5 = makeAsyncRequestPromise();

const allDone = Promise.all([
    asyncRequest1.then(() => true, () => false),
    asyncRequest2.then(() => true, () => false),
    asyncRequest3.then(() => true, () => false),
    asyncRequest4.then(() => true, () => false),
    asyncRequest5.then(() => true, () => false),
]);


allDone.then((results) => {
    const someHasFailed = results.some(result => result === false);
    if (someHasFailed) {
        // make the refresh token here
    }
});
```

Comment: While your solution would work, this is not something I can use in my app since its a whale of redux saga boilerplate and ReactJS on top of it.

The request calls are spread all over the various files in the app

Comment: Then another solution is to store the state of those requests directly into your redux store which is one additional indirection but would work